# Set up duplicate REST services with JERSEY

Tags: java, jersey

I have a working REST setup using JERSEY.  I need almost identical functionality for a different set of entities.  What do I need to do to clone this current functionality?

```
@Path("/will")
public class FileResource {

private final BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
private final BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();

/* step 1. get a unique url */

@GET
@Path("/url")
public Response getCallbackUrl() {
  /* this is /_ah/upload and it redirects to its given path */
  String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/rest/will");
  return Response.ok(new FileUrl(url), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}

/* step 2. post a file */

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void post(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
  BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("files[]");
  res.sendRedirect("/rest/will/" + blobKey.getKeyString() + "/meta");
}

....
```

Can I simply duplicate this class and change will to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical about Jersey, you can superclass as usual.  For example:

```
public class BaseResource
{

  @GET
  @Path("/url")
  public Response getCallbackUrl() {
    // Default code goes here
  }
}

@Path("/will")
public class WillResource extends BaseResource
{
  // Overrides go here
}

@Path("/abc")
public class AbcResource extends BaseResource
{
  // Overrides go here
}
```

This will give you responses for /will/url and /abc/url

Comment: I'd suggest that it is just sufficiently advanced technology, but I understand what you're saying.